# How do schools of fish get enough oxygen?

Tags: ichthyology, respiration

Fish get oxygen from the water running over their gills, during which up to ~80% of oxygen is removed from the water. In schools of fish, how do fish swimming behind other fish get enough oxygen in this case? It seems counterintuitive that the volume of unenriched water is repleted with oxygen within the fraction of a second before the fish following behind attempts to gain oxygen from it.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome. Where did you read the claim 80% of O2 is harvested? It seems like an overestimate. Further, fish move through the water and water is in motion as well - how would that affect O2 saturation?

Comment: [This beautiful paper from 1958](https://jeb.biologists.org/content/jexbio/35/4/807.full.pdf) cites a dissertation by [van Dam, 1938](https://www.rug.nl/research/portal/en/publications/on-the-utilization-of-oxygen-and-regulation-of-breathing-in-some-aquatic-animals(97d142db-6da5-493b-bcdf-a8f5cd02f93c).html), which I couldn't fully access, for the figure of 50-80%, and I see "80%" referenced widely in study resources online.  It is presumably part of a basic textbook.